# Which is the best UI option to manage business rules for drools?

Tags: drools

I need to give to the end users an options to create / edit / delete business rules for Drools.  According your experience, which is the best option?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools KIE Workbench is the only free option. Keep in mind that it takes some training to write rules so you may end up with only having developers writing and editing rules and they don't need UI for that.